# ¿Cómo obtener un dato de un JSON y usarlo en un OnItemClick para pasarlo a otra activity?

Tags: java, android, json, lista

Buenas a todos. Estoy con esta duda. Busqué temas similares a esto en la página, pero no encontré realmente una respuesta que me sirva mucho. Si se encuentra repetido les pido disculpas.

Tengo una lista que se genera de un JSON, cada objeto tiene un 'ID' y un 'Nombre'. 
Me estoy guardando ambos.

La idea es, mediante un `OnItemClick`, poder capturar el ID de ese item al que se le está haciendo click (que se encuentra en JSON) y pasarlo a otra activity, ¿Es posible?

Les dejo parte del código por si sirve de algo:

ListaContactos.java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lista_contactos);

        listaContactos = new ArrayList<>();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewContactos);
        new GetContactos().execute();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListaDatos.class);
        //intent.putExtra("idc", idc);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Click en posición: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //startActivity(intent);
    }

    private class GetContactos extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String dni = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
        private String url = "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"+username;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListaContactos.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Por favor, espere...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    JSONArray contactos= jsonObj.getJSONArray("contactos");

                    for (int i = 0; i < contactos.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contactos.getJSONObject(i);

                        String idc = c.getString("idc");
                        String nombre = c.getString("nombre");

                        HashMap<String, String> contacto = new HashMap<>();

                        contacto.put("idc", idc);
                        contacto.put("nombre", nombre);

                        listaContactos.add(contacto);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    ListaContactos.this, listaContactos,
                    R.layout.list_item_contacto, new String[]{"nombre"}, new int[]{R.id.tvNombre});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

}
```

JSON contactos:

```
{ 'contactos': [{ 'idc':'1', 'nombre': 'Centro' },{ 'idc':'2', 'nombre': 'Centro 2' },{ 'idc':'3', 'nombre': 'Norte' },{ 'idc':'4', 'nombre': 'Sur' }]}
```

Comment: Agrega por favor la estructura del json que describes para dar una respuesta acertada.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo agregué al final de la pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si al terminar el AsyncTask tienes como resultado `listaContactos` , puedes obtener el elemento de esta lista en base a su indice, que sería la variable `position`.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListaDatos.class);
    //intent.putExtra("idc", idc);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Click en posición: "+position + " Id" + listaContactos.get(position).get("idc"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //startActivity(intent);
}
```

---

Como complemento, si el elemento en `listaContactos` es un hash que se almaceno en una lista de Strings, por lo que al obtener un elemento de la lista, tendría esta estructura:

```
 {nombre=Centro, idc=1}
```

Para obtener los datos puedes usar la clase `JSONObject`, de esta forma:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


    String idc = "";
    String nombre = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(listaContactos.get(position)));
         idc = jsonObject.getString("idc");
         nombre = jsonObject.getString("nombre");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


   Toast.makeText(this, "Click en posición: "+position + " ,Id: " + idc + " ,nombre: " + nombre , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo pude solucionar. Estaba a un get de lograrlo.

Comment: @luis_snk , luis, espera aùn no terminaba de editar mi respuesta, con esto obtienes el Hash que contiene idc y nombre , pero quiero agrega como obtienes los valores mediante su key!

Comment: Hice esto:
Toast.makeText(this, "Click en posición: "+position + " Idc" + listaContactos.get(position).get("idc"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: @luis_snk he agregado la actualización que será de  màs utilidad, ya que obtienes los valores especificos de idc y nombre., saludos.

Comment: @luis_snk ok veo lo que realizaste, te funciono?=

Comment: Si, funcionó. Sólo agregando un .get("idc") después de listaContactos.get(position). Muchas gracias por responder y tomarte tu tiempo.

Comment: perfecto!, saludos!